# How to determine the degree of how high a symmetry of high-symmetry points in the first Brillouin zone?

Tags: solid-state-physics, symmetry, group-theory, graphene, x-ray-crystallography

For exmple, we have a hexagonal lattice with hexagonal Brillouin zone, shown in the picture [image]

The points $\Gamma$, K, M and $\Lambda$ are high symmetry points. Now, $\Gamma$ point is the highest-symmetry point, while others are high-symmetry points with less number of symmetries. **How to determine, what symmetries correspond to each of the symmetry points (and symmetry lines connecting them) exactly on an intuitive level?**
The way I imagine it is the following. $\Gamma$ point is zero-frequency point, i.e. particle doesn't move in the crystall structure. So all 12 symmetry operations will not change local environment that a particle feels. At M point, the particle feels an oscillating at frequency M environment, and oscillations are only along a certain direction (from $\Gamma$ to M). So, now there is no 3-fold proper or 6-fold improper rotations... **Is that the right intuitive way to look at it?**

**Is there a table of symmetries that make a correspondence of high-symmetry points (and lines) and number of symmetries that those symmetry points/lines capture?**

**What are the point groups corresponding to these symmetry points and connecting them symmetry lines for 2D hexagonal lattice?**

Note: $\Lambda$ should be treated as a symmetry line rather than a symmetry point (my sketch is misleading in this regard).

Comment: (point) symmetry operations in reciprocal space correspond to operations that leaves k vectors invariant modulo reciprocal lattice vectors